# Executing a stored procedure inside another stored procedure from a linked server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server

I'm having a problem and I don't know how to solve it, I have searched the web and found good advice but I can't work it out.

This is the problem: I have a SQL Server instance running on my PC, and I linked one of the main servers `SRVOLD\SQLDESA` to it. I want to execute main server's stored procedures from my PC's SQL Server instance and insert the results into a new table. I found the perfect way to do it using the following:

```
SELECT *   
INTO Bank   
FROM OPENQUERY([SRVOLD\SQLDESA],  
               'EXEC Bank_Database.Bank.usp_GetTDcodes 1, 5')   
GO
```

There is important information about this server, it's SQL Server version is 2008. Keep this in mind for later.

Ok so I managed to executed this Stored Procedure but I found out something, turns out that inside this Stored Procedure there's an execution of another stored procedure, check this out:

1st stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Bank.usp_GetTDcodes 
    (@code TINYINT = NULL, @qty TINYINT = NULL)
WITH ENCRYPTION 
AS
    DECLARE @@msg VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @@OK INT
    DECLARE @@today CHAR(30)

    SELECT @@today = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 112) + ' ' +
                     CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 8)

    SELECT bnk_code, bnk_descr
    FROM CODBNK
    WHERE bnk_code < 50

    EXECUTE @@OK = Bank.usp_WriteEvent  @qty, @code, @@today, 500

    IF @@OK <> 0
        RETURN @@OK

RETURN 0
GO
```

Now let's look inside the 2nd stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Bank.usp_WriteEvent
    (@code TINYINT = NULL, 
     @qty TINYINT = NULL,   
     @date DATETIME = NULL,     
     @number SMALLINT = NULL, 
     @ideve INT = 0 OUTPUT)
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
    DECLARE @@sdate VARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @@ret SMALLINT

    INSERT INTO Event (eve_code, eve_qty, eve_date, eve_number)
    VALUES (@code, @qty, @date, @number)

    SET @@ret = @@error

    IF @@ret = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @ideve = @@IDENTITY

        SELECT @@sdate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @date, 112) +  ' ' +
                         VARCHAR(30), @date, 8) 
    END
    ELSE 
        RETURN @@ret
GO
```

When I executed the 1st stored procedure, I was able to insert it's result into a new table, but I was hoping to find a new row inserted in the table `Event`, because that is the expected result when executing 2nd stored procedure.

So I started to search online and managed to achieve this by doing the following:

```
SELECT *   
INTO Bank   
FROM OPENQUERY([SRVTEST\SQLDESA],  
               'SET FMTONLY OFF;SET NOCOUNT ON;EXEC Bank_Database.Bank.usp_GetTDcodes 1, 5')   
GO
```

So, the `SET FMTONLY OFF;SET NOCOUNT ON` worked and I was happy. But something happened...

I needed to execute the same stored procedure, but this time adding a new linked server `SRVNEW\SQLDESA`. This server's version is 2012, so the new solution didn't work. I kept trying and trying different ways, there's just one way to make it work and is the following:

```
EXEC [SRVNEW\SQLDESA].[Bank_Database].Bank.usp_GetTDcodes 1,5
```

But it doesn't work for me because I need the 1st stored procedure result into a new table. And I don't know its schema that's why `SELECT INTO` works best for me. I don't know what else I can do, maybe is the `OPENQUERY` that doesn't work? Do I need to change something else?

PD: I also tried using `OPENROWSET` didn't work either.

Thanks in advance, and have a nice day! Peace!

Some references: http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#OPENQUERY

Comment: I'm wondering if you could take advantage of [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as shown in [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/223532/60085) answer to allow you to create a temp table that represents the schema being returned from SP1

Comment: Have you tried `INSERT INTO Bank EXEC [SRVNEW\SQLDESA].[Bank_Database].Bank.usp_GetTDcodes 1,5` to see if that works?

Comment: @ScottHodgin I'll take a look at that, thanks

Comment: @HandyD I thought that `INSERT INTO` required a table already created, am I correct? If that's the case, I need to create the table with the results of the 1st SP

Comment: Given the stored procedure code doesn't appear to be dynamically building a result set, wouldn't the schema of the table required be known ahead of time so you could simply create the table ahead of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the function that @Scott Hodgin suggested and created the table with that information. Thanks man!

Note: if your Stored Procedure is using a Temporary table this won't work as specified in the [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> The result could not be determined because the batch contains a
>   temporary table and is not supported by sp_describe_first_result_set.